# coffeescript ajax setinterval not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I'm newbie. 
I'm trying to make polling for changes(railscast 229) and form submission via coffeesc.

```
jQuery ->

MessagePoller =
  poll: ->
    setInterval MessagePoller.request("get_new": "yes"), 1000
    true
  request : (data) ->
    $.ajax(
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#messageform").attr("action")
      data: data
      dataType: "JSON"
    ).success (json) ->
      alert(json)
      #act on result.
    false


 $("#formsubmit").click ->
   valuesToSubmit = $("textarea#message").val()
   sendData = {"message" : valuesToSubmit}
   $("ul#messages").append("<li>" + valuesToSubmit +  "</li>")
   $("textarea#message").val('')
   MessagePoller.request(sendData)
   false # prevents normal behaviour

 MessagePoller.poll()
```

But @request works only once.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
poll: ->
  setInterval MessagePoller.request("get_new": "yes"), 1000

request : (data) ->
```

With:

```
@poll: ->
  setInterval ->(MessagePoller.request("get_new": "yes")), 1000

@request : (data) ->
```

Basically:

- you mess things up between instance and class methods
- you need a closure